# What kind of alternatively history events would have the most effect at causing a more advanced multiverse?

Tags: alternate-history

Starting July 16, 1945, our local universe has been fractured into a myriad of multiverses.

In these multiverses (not this one you are reading from right now) a number of events cause things to turn out differently than our own (Think butterfly effect). One of these multiverses has become so advanced that they have figured (a somewhat unreliable) way of jumping between multiverses.

**What kind of events could have made a multiverse more advanced than our own?**
**What kind of events would have the greatest impact, to affect this change?**

---

Some people have asked how the technology would work, so they can give a better answer. That is kinda hard info to give. It is a large handwavium plated metal box; which the protagonist discovers, when it accidentally phases into our multiverse.

Perhaps it would help thinking of what events could occur, which would let present day, present multiverse (the one you are reading this in right now) level of technological advancement, have been developed 15-20 years sooner. You can leave the advanced multiverse to extrapolate from there.

Comment: if we don't know how the navigation between multiverses work, we cannot come with a timeline to reach it.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Does the Navigation matter? The goal is to have a more advanced world, not to develop the Navigation. Just having 1990 computers work at our 2000 era computers would already accelerate most technological development and allow their people to reach the tech to navigate quicker. It is not about the navigation, but the technological advancement. Also looking at the context in July 16 1945 the Trinity nuclear test was held which could be seen as why multiverses started. So some form of advanced nuclear tech would be needed to navigate the multiverses.

Comment: @Demigan, "just an advanced world" is overly broad. Developing space travel or developing quantum computers require different advancements. That's why I ask "how does the technology work?"

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica The question is for an advanced multiverse. As broad as that is he is looking for what changes would create this advanced world. A large scale non-nuclear war between superpowers could fulfill this. The OP should definitely make it clearer what criteria he's using to identify what is the best answer as we can't know if 10 years ahead with computer science but nothing else is an acceptable answer, but as a question it isn't unclear.

Comment: Frederick Pohl covered this exact topic womderfully in *[The Coming of The Quantum Cats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Coming_of_the_Quantum_Cats)* (1986)

Answer (score 8):

## The Republic of China defeats the Communist Party of China

The PRC, and specifically Chairman Mao, are responsible for the [Great Leap Forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Leap_Forward) and the [Cultural Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_Revolution).  These two events inflicted grave damage to China culturally, scientifically, and economically.  Neither would have happened had the Chinese Civil War ended differently.

So change the outcome of said war.  I'm not versed in the history enough to know exactly how this might work, but you can probably find a way to change it involving American intervention, perhaps involving the Marshall Plan.

The previous regime had some seriously inept leadership, so get rid of them.  Put in someone competent.  Someone dangerously competent, who decides 'what we need is all the new technology we can get our hands on' and makes this a key priority of the new regime.

There are a *lot* of people in China.  The Great Leap Forward and the Cultural Revolution killed a **lot** of people, many of them the best and brightest.  If instead this were reversed, and China chose to double down on technological advancement, well, seventy years is a long time.  The existence of atoms was not really proven conclusively until Einstein's Brownian motion papers in 1905; 40 years later, nukes had been invented.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps something that would  increase in literacy in early cultural revolution era China that would have a similar knock on effect.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that you meant the alternate universes diverged at that point and were identical before.  I like DarcyThomas' suggestion and will edit my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As you mention the space race is a very important part of the technological advancement. During the time of NASA's moon projects an absolutely ridiculous amount of money was thrown into technological developments that then were used for technological advancement on the planet itself. If this had been kept up there would have been a much faster technological advancement.

Perhaps the unthinkable happened and WWIII also broke out (or a smaller large-scale conflict between the leading superpowers), but nuclear warfare was never actually started as neither group wanted to go that far knowing the consequences for the world. Warfare always sees a leap in technological advancement, with WWII seeing leaps in aircraft (pressurised cabins, better prop engine's, jet engine's which were thought to be of similar performance to props at the time etc), fuel refinement, rubber production, synthesis of various materials, metalworking and alloys, vehicle engine power and efficiency, dynamo's, energy production and so much more.

These are probably the best, most wide scale ways to improve technology on a long-term basis. You could do a few things like "oh inventor X or Y wasn't impeded or was financially backed" but those would be relatively small compared to an almost world-wide higher expenditure in technological advancement. Funnily enough perhaps the adoption of the Metric system in America could have spurred a faster development as well.

Answer (score 4):

Since the universe branching only began at the moment of the Trinity explosion, something must have been keeping it from branching up to that moment and that something must have been disabled during the blast.

By the most bizarre coincidence, the location of the trinity test just happened to also be the location where the trans-dimensional police installed the temporal stabilizer way back in the tenth century, when the region's indigenous Aztec spiritualists first induced problematic reality branching in the area.

As a side effect of someone hitting a temporal stabilizer with an atomic bomb, the entire planet is now experiencing problematic reality branching and the trans-dimensional police are completely overwhelmed by the need to neutralize the most offensive branches.  So they have totally overlooked the fact that their usually proprietary and very carefully hidden temporal stabilizer device has fallen into the hands of the Americans of branch 616, who have already cancelled their Manhattan Project initiative to focus all of their considerable scientific curiosity on the secrets of dimensional travel which the partially disabled device reveals.

It is not our recent history, but the lost history of our Aztec predecessors which exposes the potential for trans-dimensional travel, and opens up doorways to other worlds.

Comment: So this answer doesn't fit in with the rest of the plot, but there is no way you could have known that. I do lover the answer though. So full marks from me 

Answer (score 3):

Chairman Mao took a page out of Ataturk's book and moved to change to writing in China to use Latin script, but with phonetic spelling of words.

*Ataturk changed Turkey's writing to use mostly Latin script (they have 2 different I's and some letters come with bonus accents) instead of Arabic characters*

This could make it easier to teach reading and writing with all of the benefits that would enable. That and easier to interact/trade with the west later.

(In the real world, Chinese script is pretty cool. More complex abstract words can be made from a sort of 2x2 grid of simple words. Since a word is more graphical, it makes it easier to just glance at a word and know what it says based on its shape, instead of parsing each letter e.g., Flout and Flaunt)

Comment: Not so improbable. The simplification of Chinese characters was intended as one step along the eventual path of replacing pictographic characters with alphabetic letters. In our corner of the multiverse that linguistic reform project seems to have gone off the boil.

Comment: This wouldn't work. A) It already exists, it's called pinyin. B) Chinese is a terrible language for this. It's tonal and you can't express this in a latin script  and what we call Chinese is actually several different languages, with Mandarin and Cantonese being the two biggest. With a pictoral script, they can speak different languages but write the same. With phonetic, it is writing in a completely different language, which would not be easier.

Comment: @Hink: Pinyin most definitely can and actually does represent the tones; e.g., Zhōnghuá Rénmín Gònghéguó (that's People's Republic of China). Chinese script is not "pictorial"; it is a logographic script, with each characters representing a lexeme. Saying that Chinese script can represent multiple languages is like saying that the Latin alphabet can represent multiple languages -- sure it can, but if one doesn't know the other language one cannot read the text; you cannot write in Mandarin and read in Cantonese. There is a movement to use Pinyin for general purpose, with printed books etc.

Comment: "Bonus squiggles:" the Latin alphabet is used without diacritics by three languages: Latin, English and Zulu. Everybody else uses diacritics; and most New Latin texts from the 15th to the 18th century also used diacritics for good purpose. (Turkish uses diacritics not only to distinguish ı / i and g / ğ, but also to distinguish c / ç, o / ö, s / ş and u / ü.)

Comment: @AlexP You are correct about representing tones and the terminology, but I asked someone from Guangdong and you can write in Mandarin and be understood when read in Cantonese. The reverse is not true. (This is due to the familiarity with the other language) It's not impossible to have used Pinyin instead of Simplified Chinese when China changed their written language, but inefficiencies due to linguistic, economic, and political realities would make a global scientific boom an unlikely result. Especially when compared to other policy changes China may have made during the time.

Answer (score 2):

**Uplift.**

The universe that can now travel between dimensions was very much like our own.  The difference is that in the distant future, persons in that universe develop time travel, multiverse travel and a lot of other amazing tech.  The future people used their time travel tech to go back and uplift their ancestors / our contemporaries, giving them multiverse travel and all the rest as well.

Our uplifted contemporaries now have not only interdimensional travel but a treasure trove of other very advanced tech.  This tech dump was done quite hastily for reasons the future people did not disclose, and they left before walking through the uses and applications of all this tech.  Our contemporaries in this parallel dimension are very similar to ourselves, and after some truly harrowing mishaps they are slowly exploring and making sense of all the things they have been given.

Some of it they can (usually) use now, like the multidimensional hopper.    Time travel tech has so far not been predictable.  Some of the tech remains completely obscure, without instructions or anything else, and there is suspicion that the future people themselves acquired these pieces elsewhere (or elsewhen) and did not know how to use them either.

Answer (score 2):

Two changes could have drastically increased the development of software:

**1. The prevention of Alan Turing's death**

If Alan Turing was not ostracized for his sexuality, he not only would have continued to have be extremely successful after the 40s, but his suicide likely would have been prevented. If he had still been around and active for another few decades, he could have strongly affected the development of the things which he himself helped invent.

**2. More early research on neural networking**

If research on neural networks had continued and increased past the 50s instead of temporarily stopping and giving way to traditional von Neumann architecture, massive leaps could have occurred in artificial intelligence that haven't happened yet.

These things, along with others that might have helped, computers would be much farther ahead than they are now. This could result in the early creation of the "singularity" - the rise of post-human Artificial Intelligence, which could have figured out the secret to multiverses travel.

Comment: I like this answer. I have been plotting on how to make a simple mechanical neural net from (laser cut) acrylic. Not a big stretch to see that being made in the 50's

Answer (score 1):

#### Apollo 13, Space Shuttles and the Cold War

The Cold War fueled the space race and the first man on the moon. Arguably the race ended with Apollo 11 and the first men on the moon.

There were many factors that led to an incredible slowdown in manned space exploration over the coming decades, including:

- The near loss of Apollo 13 (Yes, we did keep going after that, but I am sure that near loss affected the political will to have more manned moon missions.)
- Decades later, the loss of not one but two space shuttles.
- The end of the Cold War

If we did **not** have the setbacks of Apollo 13, Challenger and Columbia, then the direct human risk and cost of manned space flight would be far lower.

If we did **not** have a largely peaceful end to the Cold War, along with some other changes (e.g., a successful Soviet manned moon landing) then by now we could easily have a further race to permanent settlements on the moon and Mars and even asteroids, and manned exploration of the outer solar system.

**And in one of those places lies the secret to multiverse travel.**

Comment: The main reason why the space race petered out is that it was originally done for mostly political reasons. The U.S. and Soviet Union weren't competing for resources or knowledge - only for bragging rights. In their eyes, whoever got to the moon first - the capitalists or the communists - would be seen as the superior form of government from history's perspective, and neither wanted that title to go to the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Sir Charles Antony Richard Hoare catches his [Billion dollar mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/) before it causes too much damage.

Sir Hoare invented the null reference. Useful, however very prone to causing errors when a computer program is running. It has by some estimates caused Billions of dollars in lost time, productivity, and broken computer systems.

If this cost did not occur, then computer systems would be cheaper and more reliable. Better computers -> more advanced technology development -> more advanced 'verse. QED